# Ext JS Issue With Window.id when more than 1 instance of Ext sandbox version is bundled

Tags: extjs

If a page has more than 1 version of Ext is Bundled which has different namespaces(sandbox version), The property `__elementIdCounter__` is shared by all the Ext namespaces, due to observed issues in Ext.cache.

assume we have 2 namespaces Ext1, Ext2 loaded to browser in the same order.

- Ext1 sets the window id as 'ext-element-1' and sets the counter varible `__elementIdCounter__` value to 1
- Ext2 sets the window id as 'ext-element-2' as the **elementIdCounter**(which is shared by both) is already 1.

Now the Ext1.get(widow) will not work as the **ext-element-2** is not available Ext1.cache.

Any idea on how to solve the issue?